# How to create Application class in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

In the [getting started](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started) guide it says:

> With Quarkus, there is no need to create an Application class. It’s supported, but not required.

But does not show how to create an application class.

How do I make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is written in a note called *Differences with vanilla JAX-RS*. The `Application` class referred to is a JAX-RS `Application` class. It typically looks like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

Perhaps more importantly, note that "there is no need to create an Application class. It’s supported, but not required" does **not** refer to creating a class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Quarkus doesn't support that (as of 1.0.0.Final; there are plans to add it in future releases).